# _type field is excluded in mongo when doing to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I am using mongo db and I got one weird problem when calling to_json method.
Suppose I have a model station. Now I can see _type attribute when I go for Station.first and even I can see the attribute when converted to json using `Station.first.to_json(:only => [:_type])` 
But the problem is simply doing ` Station.first.to_json ' just excludes _type attribute but finely shows other attributes. Can you guys help me out on this?

I am using rails 3.1.1 and mongoid 2.3.3

Comment: It is working fine in rails 3.0 & mongoid 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Station.first.to_json(:methods => :_type)`.

Comment: Works as expected. I'm using `as_json(:methods => [:_type])`